# Create XML file

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have this xml file in this format.

```
<Questions>
    <Question>
      <questiontext>The remains of the Tabon man was discovered in the Tabon Caves in     </questiontext>
      <choice1>Lipuun Point</choice1>
      <choice2>Callao Cave</choice2>
      <choice3>Hinagdanan Cave</choice3>
      <choice4>Montfort Bat Sanctuary</choice4>
      <answer>Lipuun Point</answer>
    </Question>
</Questions>
```

I'm creating this via notepad++. And read it just like this.

```
System.IO.Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("Content//Level1Trivia.xml");
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream);            
level1Trivia = new List<Trivias>();
level1Trivia = (from question in doc.Descendants("Question")
    select new Trivias()
    {
        Question = question.Element("questiontext").Value,
        Choice1 = question.Element("choice1").Value,
        Choice2 = question.Element("choice2").Value,
        Choice3 = question.Element("choice3").Value,
        Choice4 = question.Element("choice4").Value,
        Answer = question.Element("answer").Value,
    }).ToList();
```

The problem is. I can read an xml file created externally. But I don't know how to create/write xml file via code. And use my given code to read it. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the XElement object. Example:

```
XDocument document = new XDocument();
XElement rootElement = new XElement("Questions");

foreach(Question question in QuestionsCollection)
{
    XElement questionElement = new XElement("Question");

    questionElement.Add(new XElement("questiontext") { Value = question.Text });
    questionElement.Add(new XElement("choice1") { Value = question.Question1 });
    questionElement.Add(new XElement("choice2") { Value = question.Question2 });
    questionElement.Add(new XElement("choice3") { Value = question.Question3 });
    questionElement.Add(new XElement("choice4") { Value = question.Question4 });
    questionElement.Add(new XElement("answer") { Value = question.Answer });

    rootElement.Add(questionElement);
}

document.Add(rootElement);
document.Save("C:\Location.xml");
```

Something like that should work.

Comment: I will try this. How can I save it to my content folder?

Comment: By content, I assume you mean the same folder the program resides in?
There are several ways. My preferred way is just "document.Save("File.xml");", because when no drive is specified, the path is the program's running path.

Comment: Is there a way to check if file exist? Because I will try to save data to XML. And if file already exist. I want to get its data and add one set of data.

Comment: @Ijpv14: Sorry about the delay. In that case, you'd have to check if the file exists, and if so, load it into memory first. Then add the question(s?) and continue from there. Remember to overwrite the file then (which I think it does per default, when using the path of an already-existing file)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to Create and Save XML file by passing the XML save file path to the method **CreateXml**

Check out this link
[Create and Save XML file in C#/VB](http://thedevelopertips.com/DotNet/ASPDotNet/Create-and-Save-XML-file-from-Database.aspx?Id=20)

```
public void CreateXml(string XmlPath)
{ 
try
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    string Name = string.Empty;
                    int Age = 0;
                    int Experience = 0;

                    Name = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EmployeeName"].ToString();
                    Age = int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EmployeeAge"].ToString());
                    Experience = int.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["EmployeeExperience"].ToString());

                    string xml = XmlTemplate().ToString().Replace("EmpName", Name).Replace("EmpAge", Age.ToString(),Replace("EmpExperience", Experience.ToString());
                    XmlPath = XmlPath + "Employee_" + Name + ".xml";
                    XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xdoc.LoadXml(xml);
                    xdoc.Save(XmlPath);
                    lblMessage.Text = "XML Created Successfully.";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMessage.Text = "InValid Employee ID.";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
            }
}


public string XmlTemplate()
{

            string Xml = "<Employee>" +
                            "<Name>EmpName</Name>" +
                            "<Age>EmpAge</Age>" +
              "<Experience>EmpExperience</Experience>" +
                            "</Employee>";
            return Xml;
}
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.